# How can I use regex to ignore strings if they contain a certain string

Tags: regex, bash, text

I am trying to use regex to scan through some log files. In particular, I am looking to pick out lines that meet this format:

IP address or random number "banned.", so for example, "111.111.111.111 banned." or "0320932 banned.", etc.

There should only be 2 groups of characters (the number/IP address and "banned." There may be more than one space in between the words or before them), the string should also not contain "client", "[private]", or "request". For the most part I am just confused about how to go about detecting the groups of characters and avoiding strings that contain those words.

Thanks for any help that you may have to offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
egrep -v '^ *[0-9]+((\.[0-9]+){3})? +banned\.$'
```

- Allows optional leading spaces at the beginning of the line.
- Must be followed by an all-digit sequence OR an IP-like address.
- Must be followed by at least one space.
- Line must end in 'banned.'
- Finally, the `-v` option ensures that only lines NOT matching the regex are returned.

With these constraints you needn't worry about ruling out additional words such as 'client'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming in the following input data lines 1 and 3 should be dropped:

```
111.111.111.111 banned.
2.2.2.2 wibble
0320932 banned
1434324 wobble
```

You can drop them with this `grep` expression:

```
$ grep -E -v "[0-9.]+ +banned" logfile.log 
2.2.2.2 wibble
1434324 wobble

$
```

This regular expression matches 1 or more numbers and periods followed by 1 or more spaces followed by the word "banned".  Passing `-v` to grep will cause it to display all lines that **do not** match the regular expression. Add `-i` to the `grep` command to make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegExp

```
String regex = "\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+ banned.";
```

Here you can filter your both kind of string.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("start");
    String src = "657 hi tis is 111.111.111.111 banned. 57 happy i9";
    //String src = "87 working is 0320932 banned. Its ending str 08";
    String regex = "\\d+.\\d+.\\d+.\\d+ banned.";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);

    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.start() + " : " + matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Let me know if it is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want a negating match, which looks like:

```
/^((?!([\d.\s]+banned\.)).)*$/
```

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/bY7pK4

**Note** your example shows a period after `banned`. If you don't want it, remove `\.` from the expression.

Answer (score 1):

> trying to match `IP address or random number "banned."`

This `egrep` should work for you:

```
egrep '(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]+) +banned' logfile
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will work:

```
\s*\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\s*banned\s*
```

Comment: This answer has too many problems to list them all in a comment.  You really should test your solutions before you post them.